# Discord.js - setNickname has not enough permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i am using discord.js to make a very simple bot,

when i call `message.member.setNickname("Another Nickname").then(console.log, console.log);`

i get

```
{
  name: 'DiscordAPIError',
  message: 'Missing Permissions',
  method: 'patch',
  path: '...',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

But the permissions of the bot are:
[506981977](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#506981977)

And `message.guild.member(client.user).permissions.has("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")` is returning `true`

Comment: Make sure the bot's highest role is above the highest role of the member who's nickname you want to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the bot's highest role is above the highest role of the member who's nickname you want to change. You can check this with the [`comparePositionTo()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo) method, and the [`GuildMember.roles.highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=highest) property.

```js
// <user> is a placeholder for the user who's nickname you are changing
if (client.user.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(<user>.roles.highest) > 0)
  return console.log("Client cannot change the user's nickname");
```

Comment: I just realized that i am the owner and the bot can't change to owners name 